# Add class to parent LI where A = current document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a class to an LI automatically if the filename matches the href (e.g; if the anchor has the href attribute set to about.php and the filename of the current page is about.php then it would append the class.) however, along the way I've hit some complications and I've been getting myself confused with the syntax a little...

So far I have this...

```
var filename = location.pathname.substring(1)

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
        if (this.href === filename) {
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('current_page_item');
        }
    });
});
```

My navigation is constructed as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sgySp/3/) and as you can see, it works and everything but only when the class is set manually... so I'm trying to get it to be automatic from the actual filename.

I hope this make some sense to someone, as I'm really confused on how to get this working now!

Thank-you to anyone who contributes, it's of great help and will help me understand the jquery syntax further, actually selecting something specific and writing a logical statement in jquery really confuses me as it's very different to PHP, which is what I'm used to.

My markup looks like this, since I didn't include it before and just *assumed* people would look at the source code to understand what I was meaning (though, I should have put it here)

```
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="group" id="effects">
            <li><a href="index.php" title="View the latest news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php" title="Find out more about us">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Find out about races">Races</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Find out what tools we use">Tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Read the Frequently Asked Questions">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php" title="Contact us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show (a representative/minimal sample of) your mark-up in your question; Stack Overflow is meant to be self-contained for questions and answers to guard against link-rot.

Comment: You should really be doing this with PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match url folders with a tag href to make a active state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564539/match-url-folders-with-a-tag-href-to-make-a-active-state)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349046/add-active-class-to-the-current-pages-link-in-a-menu-using-jquery-or-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608974/jquery-if-the-href-attribute-for-an-element-is-equal-to-the-href-attribute-for-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it as simple as this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').filter(function() {
      return (this.href == location.href);
    }).parent('li').addClass('current_page_item');
});
```

​Filter the anchor tags by their href attribute.  Seems to work on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/sgySp/).  For some reason, you have to hit run for it to work.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle and I did try your code with it, it didn't seem to animate and correctly display the line under the navigation when I added the code without appending the class to the markup... You can see for yourself now if you were to remove it and try your script, it'd just be a big inanimate line.

I appreciate the help and effort you've provided, thank-you. :)

Comment: Uh, I thought I added the link but I guess I didn't? [JSFiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/sgySp/3/)

Comment: @Volvagia It works. It's just messing up because it's on JSFiddle: go to this link: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/sgySp/18/. And hit Run, and you'll see the purple bar under RACES.

Comment: Wow! Thank-you! This work! Now I just need to get rid of the inline styling somehow, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that li tag is parent of anchor tag than you can try this-

```
$(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
```

instead:

```
$(this).parent('li').addClass('current_page_item');
```

Comment: And how does that help dynamically assign the class based on the current page and the `a` element's `href`?

Comment: I tried this, but like David said it doesn't really help dynamically assign the class based on the document name and the navigation's href element. Thank-you for trying to help though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what little information you've provided in your question, I'd suggest (though this is untested):

```
var file = document.location.href.split('/').pop();
$('li a').filter(function(){
    return this.href.indexOf(file) !== -1;
}).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
```

This gets the contents of the current page's URL and splits it by the `/` character and then assigns the last element of the array to the variable `file`, for example:

```
'http://example.com/directory/page.html'
```

is converted into an array:

```
["http:", "", "example.com", "directory", "page.html"]
```

And the last element of that array is assigned to the variable, so `file` becomes equal to:

```
'page.html'
```

The jQuery iterates over every `a` element within an `li` element and then, if it finds the string `page.html` within the `href` attribute it returns that `a` element, and adds the class-name to its parent element.

You could, instead, use the full `document.location.href`, of course; which would give:

```
var page = document.location.href;
$('li a').filter(function(){
    return this.href == page;
}).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
```

This works much the same way, but instead of looking to see if the filename can be found within the URL, it checks that the `href` of the element is *exactly* equal to the current `document.location.href`.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).
  - [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
    *jQuery:
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: This is all great information and it's great to see someone know what they're talking about, I'm really not used to working with jQuery myself so this is all great stuff. I couldn't actually get it to work myself though, there's a JSFiddle in bozdoz's comment that I put everything into, I also tried your code there and probably just by lack of knowledge with working with jQuery I couldn't get it to display properly... Thank-you for the input and advice though, it's great to hear from someone who seems to have a lot of knowledge...

Comment: The problem may well be JS Fiddle itself, unless you've copied the URL into the `href` of one of the links on your page?

Comment: @Volvagia: for example, once the page is rendered in JS Fiddle, the links' `href` attribute is [comiled differently than you might imagine](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yLHc5/). Try this in a page you control (where the `href` and the `document.location` are reasonably, and predictably, under your control).

Comment: I'm editing it in my localhost because I thought it was a problem with the way jquery compiled the attribute, but I'm still getting the same problem... The class just simply isn't applied, I'm probably doing something wrong though. Ugh, sorry for being such a pain.